# Find shortest path using A*

Tags: java, shortest-path, dijkstra, a-star

I am making a game where a pawn must be escorted to node F. The values stored in the 2D array represent:

```
Pawn (starting point): I    
Destination: F
```

For example,

```
Node [row=2, col=1]
Node [row=2, col=2]
Node [row=1, col=2]
Node [row=0, col=2]
Node [row=0, col=3]
Node [row=0, col=4]
Node [row=1, col=4]
Node [row=2, col=4]
Node [row=2, col=5]

Search Path without diagonals
     0   1   2   3   4   5   6
0    -   -   *   *   *   -   -
1    -   -   *   B   *   -   -
2    -   I*  *   B   *  *F   -
3    -   -   -   B   -   -   -
4    -   -   -   -   -   -   -
5    -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

The problem with my implementation is that it goes through move by move. I want to be able to detect when the direction changes and only add this move, how can I accomplish this? For example, instead of visiting all the nodes one by one like in my example from before, I want:

```
Node [row=2, col=1] 
Node [row=2, col=2] // Right

Node [row=0, col=2] // Top

Node [row=0, col=4] // Right

Node [row=2, col=4] // Bottom
Node [row=2, col=5] // Right
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking how you can modify the A star algorithm that you're using to give you the output you want, or can you just modify the output of the algorithm to get your desired output?

Comment: Modify the A* star algorithm

Comment: From my understanding of the A* algorithm (anyone is welcome to correct me), what you're asking for is impossible. You can only skip nodes to get the output you desire when you already know you have the shortest path.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant I want to modify the output. Sorry about that -_-

Comment: Then check @default locale 's answer because his solution does exactly what you need.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now it contains a working solution that works as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't check the algorithm implementation, but tt appears that you're getting your result as a list of Node objects. It probably looks like something like this:

```
List<Node> path = aStar.findPath();
```

Then all you need to do is to exclude all intermediate nodes from the result. You can do this after an actual algorithm (DISCLAIMER: untested code):

```
List<Node> path = aStar.findPath();
//a path with intermediate nodes removed
List<Node> filteredPath = new ArrayList<>(path.size());
for(int i=0; i<path.size(); i++) {
    Node current = path.get(i);
    //the first and the last element get into the result in any case
    if(i==0 || i==path.size()-1) {
          filteredPath.add(current);
    } else {
          //for the elements in between we are detecting the direction change
          Node previous = path.get(i-1);
          Node next = path.get(i+1);
          //is the step from the previous node to this one vertical
          boolean isPreviousStepVertical = current.getCol()==previous.getCol();
          //is the step from this node to the next one vertical
          boolean isNextStepVertical = current.getCol()==next.getCol();
          //we only add the nodes for which the direction has changed
          if(isPreviousStepVertical!=isNextStepVertical) {
               filteredPath.add(current);
          }

    } 
}
```

The idea is to check for each node if the direction actually changes (from vertical to horizontal, or vice versa) and only keep the necessary nodes.

I assume that a pawn can't move diagonally and can't move back to the already visited cell. Otherwise, you'd need to calculate the actual vectors of direction between nodes and compare them to each over.

**UPDATE:** To make your AStar implementation work as intended you need to comment out four lines that correspond to diagonal moves in `addAdjacentUpperRow` and `addAdjacentLowerRow`, e.g.:

```
checkNode(currentNode, col - 1, upperRow, getDiagonalCost()); // Comment this if diagonal movements are not allowed
```

After this, everything works as expected: https://ideone.com/77MAxg

Comment: You should probably test your code, because this doesn't do what OP wants.

Comment: @JohnKim Could you elaborate on that? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: Actually *I* was the one who was wrong. Your code indeed does work, my input was using diagonal paths, not horizontal paths like in OP's example. I was looking over your code again and realized the code couldn't possibly be wrong, lol

Comment: @JohnKim How did you test it? I've actaully tried to [run the code](https://ideone.com/nFwE2m). Turns out, the filtering works just fine. `AStar` on the other hand doesn't produce the initial result correctly. I have no idea why. My answer contains a disclaimer that I didn't validate the code of `AStar`.

Comment: @JohnKim By the way, if you have the implementation of an algorithm that works as intended then you should probably post it here so the OP has the complete working solution.

Comment: My implementation looks exactly the same as yours, and produced the same (what I thought was) wrong output. Which was how I realized I was using the wrong input to begin with.

Comment: @JohnKim Turns out, all I had to do was to exclude a couple of lines. Now, everything's OK.